# How to get Processing Type from Controller (Rails)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, webrick

When an HTTP request comes into the server (in this case I'm running `rails s` which defaults to webrick) the message looks something like:

```
Started POST "/cards" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-05 15:04:29 -0400
  Processing by CardsController#create as JS
```

I'm wondering how to get the value JS in this case, or HTML. Sorry I can't be more explicit, I'm not sure what that value is called. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `request.format` to get the format. It'll return "text/javascript" for JS requests, "text/html" for HTML, "application/json" for JSON, etc.

Also, you would typically use this in a `respond_to` block:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { do something }
  format.js { do something else }
end
```